# The relative modules were not found in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have tried every thing but it doesn't work for me, I provide router
setup link, but it throws me an exception

> These relative modules were not found:
>
> ./AppContact.vue; in ./src/main.js
>   ./AppHome.vue in ./src/main.js
>   ./AppLogin.vue in ./src/main.js
>   ./AppToolbar.vue; in ./src/main.js

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import AppToolbar from './AppToolbar.vue;'
import AppContact from './AppContact.vue;'
import AppLogin from './AppLogin.vue';
import AppHome from './AppHome.vue';
Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const routes =[
  {path:'/',components:App},
  {path:'/AppToolbar',components:AppToolbar},
  {path:'/AppContact',components:AppContact},
  {path:'/AppLogin',components:AppLogin},
  {path:'/AppHome',components:AppHome}
];
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode:'history'
});
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    <router-view> </router-view>router-view>
     <app-footer style="position:absolute;z-index:-1"></app-footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AppToolbar from './components/AppToolbar'
import AppFooter  from './components/AppFooter'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    AppToolbar,AppFooter
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Remove the `;` from the paths

i.e: `'./AppToolbar.vue;'` should be `'./AppToolbar.vue';`

### 2. Point to the correct directory

which I'm guessing is `components`

---

#### Main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import AppToolbar from './components/AppToolbar.vue';
import AppContact from './components/AppContact.vue';
import AppLogin from './components/AppLogin.vue';
import AppHome from './components/AppHome.vue';

// etc...
```